# SDL window does not open correctly

Tags: c, sdl

I am learning to use the SDL library. However, amongst the many problems I faced, there is one for which I find no solution on the Internet. I set the video mode characteristics with `SDL_SetVideoMode`, but there is no new window that appears when I run the program. The only thing that happens is that my terminal shows a strange pattern but that does not look like the window I should have, and even if it did, it **does not** open a new window. This happens in the shell window in which I tried to run the program.

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

void    pause(void)
{
    int     on = 1;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (on == 1)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                on = 0;
        }
    }
}

int     main(void)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    else
    {
        SDL_SetVideoMode(1024, 576, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
        SDL_WM_SetCaption("SDL TEST", NULL);
        pause();
        SDL_Quit();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I use a Makefile, this is what is inside of it:

```
FLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror
SDLFLAG=-lSDL
NAME=sdl1

all: ${NAME} clean

${NAME}: ${NAME}.o
    gcc -o ${NAME} ${NAME}.o ${FLAGS} ${SDLFLAG}

${NAME}.o: ${NAME}.c
    gcc -o ${NAME}.o -c ${NAME}.c ${FLAGS} ${SDLFLAG}

clean:
    rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
    rm -rf ${NAME}
```

And the result of running the program is the following:
[image]

What is happening? Why don't I have a new, empty window, named, "SDL TEST"?

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. You are not executing the correct program.

Comment: thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using SDL1 when SDL2 is out and stable

Comment: I followed the instructions on this site: loka.developpez.com/tutoriel/sdl/installation/linux, I see that it hasn't been updated in the last 11 years! Like you say, I must have installed an older version of SDL and it may be the reason why my program doesn't work... I'll search for a way to get SDL2 via linux bash.

Comment: I have installed SDL2 via the command `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev`, I have all the .h files in `usr/include/SDL2`, and I use the header `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`. Yet the  problem remains, so I guess it's not a problem of version. the answer below my question makes me think that my code is not executed by the correct program. I don't know, it is highly unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the SDL library tries to display your window using [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca)

First try, if you can open a connection to your XServer by executing for example `xterm` in your shell. If that works, try to start it with

```
SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11 ./sdl1
```

to force the usage of the x11 video driver and see, if it works properly.

Comment: I typed "xterm" in my shell and it told me this: http://zupimages.net/up/17/21/87rt.png

Comment: @nounoursnoir Well, that is probably the reason why SDL chooses libcaca over x11.  You will have to fix your environment to get it working. A `export DISPLAY=:0` might be worth a try.

Comment: I tried `export DISPLAY=:0` and then tried to use my program again. The good thing is that it didn't do the weird screen that I had before (the one which you can see in a screenshot in the original question). The bad thing is that after 1 or 2 seconds of waiting, the `SDL_Init` line is doing a segfault :(

Comment: @nounoursnoir Hm, you will really have to make the xterm command work, then chances are good that your SDL-Program will work, too

Comment: After using `export DISPLAY=:0`, I tried using `SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11 ./sdl1` and my program didn't segfault anymore. The thing is: I have no idea what changed, I have no idea what this command is supposed to do. I can only tell what I see... Another detail that, I think, I should bring to your attention is that the call `SDL_Init` failed: `(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)` evaluated `true`...

Comment: How do I do to make the xterm command work? I am lost I don't really understand what xterm is even after reading the manual.

Comment: @nounoursnoir Are you saying that SDL fails to initialize?

Comment: yes it did, since the return value of `SDL_Init` is -1